# Confirmation for nth roots of unity question and answer.

Tags: complex-numbers

Hi Can I just get someone to confirm my answer is right for the following:

I want to find all values of $1^{\frac{1}{5}}$. So I worked these out to be 
$1e^{0i}, 1e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}, 1e^{\frac{2\pi i}{10}}, 1e^{\frac{2\pi i}{15}}, 1e^{\frac{2\pi i}{20}}$. Just making sure my angles are correct? I've just added $\frac{2\pi i}{5}$ to each preceeding angle.

Secondly, I want to find the linear factors of $P(z) = 1+z+z^2+...+z^8$. So, just to be sure, I am looking for the $9th$ roots of unity which are $(z-e^{{\frac{2\pi ki}{9}}})$ where k = 0,...,8?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to know whether $\zeta_i$ is an nth root of unity you don't need to ask us, just take $\zeta_i^n$. In exponential form as you have given them this is fairly direct application of the arithmetic of exponents.

Comment: Thanks but what I'm somewhat confused with as well is if I'm looking for 8th or 9th roots of unity here. I think it is 9 but the power of 8 is slightly throwing me. And I'm making sure that my formula above is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, you have the right idea but have not made it work properly. The right answer is $1=e^{\frac{0\pi i}{5}}$, $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$, $e^{\frac{4\pi i}{5}}$, $e^{\frac{6\pi i}{5}}$, $e^{\frac{8\pi i}{5}}$.

For the second one: your answer would be correct for the polynomial $z^9-1=(z-1)\cdot P(z)$. For $P(z)$ you must omit the factor $z-1$, i.e. $k$ will go from $1$ to $8$, rather than from $0$ to $8$.

Comment: Thank you, yes sorry I see how I made a mistake on the first one. So just making sure - am I looking for the 8th or 9th roots of unity for the second question?

Comment: They are 9th roots of unity, but not all of them. In particular, $1$ is a 9th root of unity, but not the one you are looking for. The other $8$ 9th roots of unity are ok.